# What is wrong with my Python turtle code that creates a Sierpinski fractal?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, computational-geometry, python-turtle

[image]

```
import turtle
import random
import math
import time

def is_point_inside_shape(x, y, vertices):
    # Use ray-casting algorithm to check if point is inside the shape
    num_intersections = 0
    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        p1 = vertices[i]
        p2 = vertices[(i+1) % len(vertices)]
        if p1[2] <= y < p2[2] or p2[2] <= y < p1[2]:
            if x < (p2[0] - p1[0]) * (y - p1[2]) / (p2[2] - p1[2]) + p1[0]:
                num_intersections += 1
    return num_intersections % 2 == 1

def add_points(num_sides, side_length, iterations, distance, speed):
    # Set up the turtle
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.speed(10)
    t.ht()
    t.penup()

    # Create vertices
    vertices = []
    angle = 2 * math.pi / num_sides
    for i in range(num_sides):
        x = side_length * math.cos(angle * i)
        y = side_length * math.sin(angle * i)
        vertices.append((x, y))

    # Draw the outline of the shape
    t.goto(vertices[0])
    t.pendown()
    for i in range(num_sides):
        t.goto(vertices[i])
    t.goto(vertices[0])

    # Draw a random point inside the shape
    t.penup()
    while True:
        x, y = random.uniform(-side_length/2, side_length/2), random.uniform(-side_length/2, side_length/2)
        if is_point_inside_shape(x, y, vertices):
            # Draw the point and break the loop
            t.goto(x, y)
            t.dot(4, 'red')
            break

    # Iterate and draw points
    t.speed(speed)
    for i in range(iterations):
        # Choose a random vertex
        vertex = random.choice(vertices)

        # Calculate the distance between the current position and the chosen vertex
        dx = (vertex[0] - t.xcor()) * distance
        dy = (vertex[2] - t.ycor()) * distance

        # Move the turtle to the new position
        t.goto(t.xcor() + dx, t.ycor() + dy)

        # Draw a dot at the new position
        t.dot(2, 'blue')

    # Done drawing
    t.penup()
    turtle.done()

#add_points(num_sides, side_length, num_points, distance from vertex, speed)
add_points(5, 250, 10000, 0.5, 3)
```

I am writing a program using python turtle that generates an equilateral polygon with a given number of sides. A random point is placed inside the polygon and the next point is some distance in between the previous point and a random vertex of the polygon (the default behavior is halfway). This is supposed to create a fractal. The program seems to work when I create any polygon except a square, where the dots don't seem to create a pattern.

Comment: Can you show what it looks like for 3, 4, and 5 sides?

Comment: In `is_point_inside_shape`, what happens in the case where `p1[1] == p2[1]` or `p1[0] == p2[0]` ?

Comment: Just added pictures for the output with a triangle, square, and pentagon

Comment: You have `vertex[2]` and `p1[2]` and `p2[2]`, but your points only have 2 coordinates.  Those should all be `[1]`.

Comment: Why do you think this should work for polygons with more than 3 sides?  I'm not saying it doesn't, but I certainly can't find a reference.  When I run your code for 5 sides, it doesn't look like a fractal, either.  It also looks random.

Comment: There is only one image with a triangle, you forgot the other two images.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing wrong with the posted code is that you appear to have broken  the function `is_point_inside_shape()` in a follow up edit to your original post by changing the `[0]` and `[1]` indexes to `[0]` and `[2]` which causes an index error.  Put 'em back!

Beyond that, the second thing wrong with your code is that it's perfectly fine -- read this [Wolfram article](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1025180) where it explains that with a distance from vertex of 1/2, you'll get a random distribution for a square.  However, a distance of 2/3 for a square produces a nice fractal.

Finally, my rework of your code so I could play with this stuff:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D
from random import uniform, choice
from math import pi, cos, sin

def is_point_inside_shape(x, y, vertices):
    # Use ray-casting algorithm to check if point is inside the shape

    num_intersections = 0

    for index, p1 in enumerate(vertices):
        p2 = vertices[(index+1) % len(vertices)]

        if p1[1] <= y < p2[1] or p2[1] <= y < p1[1]:
            p3 = p2 - p1

            if x < p3[0] * (y - p1[1]) / p3[1] + p1[0]:
                num_intersections += 1

    return num_intersections % 2 == 1

def add_points(num_sides, side_length, iterations, distance, speed):
    turtle.speed(speed)

    # Create vertices
    vertices = []
    angle = pi*2 / num_sides

    for i in range(num_sides):
        x = side_length * cos(angle * i)
        y = side_length * sin(angle * i)
        vertices.append(Vec2D(x, y))

    # Draw the outline of the shape
    turtle.penup()

    for vertex in vertices:
        turtle.goto(vertex)
        turtle.pendown()

    turtle.goto(vertices[0])
    turtle.penup()

    # Draw a random point inside the shape

    while True:
        x, y = uniform(-side_length/2, side_length/2), uniform(-side_length/2, side_length/2)

        if is_point_inside_shape(x, y, vertices):
            # Draw the point and break the loop
            turtle.goto(x, y)
            turtle.dot(4, 'red')
            break

    # Iterate and draw points

    for _ in range(iterations):
        # Calculate the distance between the current position and the chosen vertex
        delta = (choice(vertices) - turtle.position()) * distance

        # Move the turtle to the new position
        turtle.goto(turtle.position() + delta)

        # Draw a dot at the new position
        turtle.dot(2, 'blue')

    # Done drawing
    turtle.penup()

screen = Screen()

# Set up the turtle
turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

# add_points(num_sides, side_length, num_points, distance from vertex, speed)
add_points(3, 250, 10000, 1/2, 'fastest')

screen.exitonclick()
```